# form goes behind <ion-header> in IONIC

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

Ionic Form's top item goes behind ion-header. Below is the HTML.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton color="dark">
      <button ion-button  menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>REGISTER</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class='has-header'>
  <form [formGroup]="todo" (submit)="logForm()" padding class="bg-register-image">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="emaill" type="email" formControlName="emaill"></ion-input>{{emaill}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="Password" type='password' formControlName="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <button ion-button block position="bottom" type="submit" item-left [disabled]="!todo.valid">Submit</button>
      <button block ion-button color="secondary" [navPush]="homepage" item-left>CANCEL</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Let me know what to change. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post whole page at once?

Comment: please post the entire html of this page for anyone to help you

Comment: Have you tried adding a margin to top of the page with the form ?

Comment: what does `has-header` class contain? did you set any css for ion-content?